CSS file only works with live server on visual studio code
I backed up my files on Github and now the CSS file ONLY works when I open it through a live server. It does does work when I select view with default browser nor when I open the html file.
i tried looking online for help, I tried relinking the CSS page. The code is fine and works with live server only.
this is how I linked the CSS:
<link rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" href="/Root Directory/first-fantastic-engine-1/Root Folder/Home page/Fun project/CSS/style.css"/>

Im new to coding and I made alot of files a while back for my code.

Have you check what error you get on browser console? most common error is setting wrong path

Your directory organisation is 6 levels deep and your directory names have spaces in them. I generally also recommend using only lower-case letters.
This is making your job very difficult.
Something like
root
|-------css
|-------js
|-------images
will save you a world of worries.
A quick use of your browser's developer tools will no doubt quickly reveal the problem.

When i first started off I made too many folder by accident yes. Should I rename these folders?

Like the others have suggested, it could just be an issue with path. Hard to provide the definite answer without taking a look at the error. If you can provide that it would make things easier.
As far as folder structure goes, there are some basic principles that you can follow such as using camelCase or kebab-case.
Take a look at this - https://ecss.benfrain.com/chapter5.html
Folder structure and naming conventions are some of the first things i would recommend to learn if you are a newbie.

When i just started my coding I created too many files. Should I change the file names now?

If you are building a project for long term or something you want to showcase in your GIT then i would definitely suggest changing file and folder names and folder structure to match industry standard. Makes sure your project is loaded correctly in any environment.
BTW since you haven't confirmed the answer or other suggestions, was the path your issue? If not do let us know what was it.

Im just working on a practice project for now, I dont want to make it public. Ill name the files correctly on my new public project.

as for the CSS not loading default server the file paths are linked correctly i checked a few times. However this is the error that shows up on the dev tools : Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Naming the files and folders correctly is not for public. Its for the compiler/transpiler.
If your path for href or url has space it will not work. Try renaming folders and file without spaces. If you don't want to change that try using %20 instead of space in href and see if it works.

I tied both but it still isnt working

This was just a practice project. If I were to create a public project what is the first step? From the basics of creating the files to launching it. I use VScode, Git, Github and Github Desktop.
